# When and why does the TRUNC(DATE, [FORMAT]) used in the real world

Tags: sql, oracle, truncate

I am getting into Oracle database. I came across the `TRUNC(DATE, [FMT])` function. I am not really clear on it except it seems to return the beginning value of some sort?

Can somebody educate me on it? When or what would it be used for at work, or why somebody might want to use the function?

Comment: *"it returns the beginning value or some sort???"* Did you read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/TRUNC-date.htm#SQLRF06151)? Which part of the documentation is confusing you as to what the function does? It even have a nice example of what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another thing it is useful for is to get the time component of the current day. I use an expression like this all the time:

```
SELECT sysdate - trunc(sysdate) AS TodaysTime FROM DUAL
```

Because the system date is stored in a decimal format (e.g. `sysdate = 42651.2426897456`) and the integer value corresponds to midnight, I can use the above statement to get only the decimal portion (e.g. `TodaysTime = 0.2426897456`, or just before 6 AM).

There may be easier ways to do this, but in my applications this has been the easiest as I frequently need to work with only the day's time component.

Comment: I have to look up the decimal format.  LOL!  I would of never known something like that was available.  Learned something new.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query to know when it might be usefull:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';

select  sysdate,
        trunc( sysdate, 'mi' ) As beginning_of_current_minute,
        trunc( sysdate, 'mi' ) As beginning_of_current_hour,
        trunc( sysdate, 'dd' ) As beginning_of_current_day,
        trunc( sysdate, 'iw' ) As beginning_of_current_week,
        trunc( sysdate, 'mm' ) As beginning_of_current_month,
        trunc( sysdate, 'q' ) As beginning_of_current_Quarter,
        trunc( sysdate, 'y' ) As beginning_of_current_Year
FROM dual;
```

---

An example - you want to get all orders starting from the beginning of the current week:

```
SELECT *
FROM ORDERS
WHERE order_date >= trunc( sysdate, 'iw' )
```

Comment: If you like this unswer then please [upvote it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) thank you.

Comment: Will do.  I think the third column, beginning_of_current_hour should be hh.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

A real world example would be if you wanted to aggregate results from a table by year.  You could use the TRUNC function like this:

```
SELECT TRUNC(my_date, 'YEAR') the_year, count(*)
FROM some_table
GROUP BY TRUNC(my_date, 'YEAR');
```

...which would return a set of results with the first column the date truncated to the beginning of the year and the second column a count of all the records with dates within that year.

```
the_year, count(*)
_________________
01-JAN-12, 543
01-JAN-13, 1268
01-JAN-14, 1134
01-JAN-15, 1765
```

There are obviously other ways to achieve the same thing, but this is a real world example of how you might use TRUNC.

Another might be if you are comparing dates and you only want to use a certain degree of precision.  If you have a timestamp column and you want all the records for today, you could select based on a range where the timestamp is greater than midnight yesterday and less than midnight today, or you could select where the timestamp, truncated to the DATE, is equal to today.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29805_01/server.230/es_eql/src/cdfp_analytics_lang_trunc.html

Comment: Thanks for your example.  I just did not see how to use it before.